# How can I control an ESC with an STM32F303K8

Tags: stm32, motor-controller

I couldn't find any documentation about it.
The STM32 nucleo should control a brushless motor, with the speed depending on changing data.
The ESC I'm using is a BHELI_S.
Edit: I'm using CubeIDE and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do is to use rc servo signal similar to throttling signal from receiver.
For more advance protocol like D-Shot, Multi-shot there are no library for that yet. You need to generate waveform by your self.